# When we set $c=1$ and $\hbar=1$, why is energy still measured in $eV$?

Tags: atomic-physics, dimensional-analysis, units, unit-conversion, absolute-units

When we set $c=1$ and $\hbar=1$, we often see in particle physics that mass and energy are expressed in terms of $eV$.

This doesn't make sense to me. If we are choosing a new unit system where for example the units are $apple$ for length, $bear$ for time and $cat$ for mass such that speed of light $c=1 \frac{apple}{bear}$, shouldn't the mass in this unit system be expressed in terms of $cat$ and energy in terms of $cat \frac{apple^2}{bear^2} $? Why are we still using $eV$? It is not a valid unit in the new unit system.

I also thought that maybe setting $c=1$ and $\hbar=1$ is just a useful mathematical trick by letting $$3\times 10^8m=1s$$
$$6.6 \times 10^{-16} eV = 1 s^{-1}$$
so that $c$ and $\hbar$ disappear in our equations. In other words, we are not actually using another unit system but just doing a mathematical manipulation for ease of calculation. But this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51791/) says that we are indeed using another unit system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You appear to have misunderstood the natural system of units. Most HEP courses cover it on the very first lecture on the subject (at least Feynman's did).

The system reorients [L], [M], [T] to [V],[S],[E], namely speed, action (or angular momentum) and energy, respectively, and then measures speed in units of *c*, action in units of  ℏ, and energy in units of  eV.

So your apple/bear/cat paradigm is flawed. *c* is 1 in units of *c*, and *x*=something in units of apple/bear. Nobody set *c=1* in *those* units!

Likewise, ℏ is 1 in units of ℏ. As a result, all quantities are in units of $(\hbox{eV})^a~ \hbar^b~ c^d$, but, ***if you know their dimension***, you may skip *d* and *b* and only measure them in units of energy, so eV.

You may *then* reinstate the units of speed and action by dimensional analysis, ***uniquely***, since you know their dimension,  if you need to communicate the final result (a frequency/rate, etc...) to an engineer for a macroscopic measurement. But since the  contact points of HEP to the macroscopic world are limited, you very-very-very rarely need to do that, and you live a life of one unit.

Try an example. Can you see how , e.g., lengths are measured in units of
ℏ*c*/eV; masses in eV/$c^2$; and lifetimes in ℏ/eV ?

Comment: In my HEP class the professor simply said we let $c=1$, $\hbar =1$ because they are tedious. This cleared my confusion thanks.